# typedef error under gcc

Tags: c

in my code, I put following codes

```
typedef Status int;
```

I got following errors, it is expected '=', ',', ';', 'asm' or '**attribute**' before 'int' under linux.

I can't find what's probelm. Thanks for your help.
a

Comment: For what it's worth, I always memorize the order by remembering that it's *not* like `#define`. With `#define`, the "new" value (symbol) is the first argument. So with `typedef`, it's the second.

Answer (score 6):

Use:

```
typedef int Status;
```

instead of

```
typedef Status int;
```

The syntax of a `typedef` is the same as the syntax as any ordinary declaration:

```
int a, b;          // declare int objects a and b
typedef int c, d;  // declare int type-aliases c and d
```

Answer (score 1):

The typedef should be followed by the type and then the name. Therefore, the typedef should look like this:

```
typedef int Status;
```

Answer (score 0):

The syntax for typedef is

```
typedef <SOME_TYPE> new_name_for_some_type;
```

You are swapping the <SOME_TYPE> and new_name_for_some_type elements of the `typedef` syntax.